# Insect identification request : is it any species from muscidae family or some another?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I belong to Haryana , India
Sudden I found this type of insect in my classroom
and it stung me suddenly because ,I felt itching in my hand for about 15 mins , so please tell me, is it poisonous or not and which type of Arthropod is it ?
Characteristics:-
Two horn like protrusions on its head ,

A stingy tail,

Eyes are not clearly visible,

Winged ,

1-1.5cm in size
(Sorry for blurred image )

[image]

Comment: The photo is far to unclear to be able to tell anything other than "winged insect" I can't even tell if it could be a bee or a fly.

Comment: I got it , it is a horned treehopper which is found in UK, US and India

Comment: From the wings, it must be an [Auchenorrhyncha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auchenorrhyncha), likely a Membracidae species. So, I wonder how it could have bitten or stung anyone... 
This one looks similar and occurs in India: https://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/16531012

Comment: I am also confused that , which type of eyes this treehopper has ..... These are not ommatidia not simple eyes but which type

Answer (score 0):

It's a treehopper (membracidae) from the genus *Oxyrachis*. They do not sting or bite. Identifying the species is impossible due to the quality of the image, but here are a few:

[image]
*O. tarandus*

[image]
*O. versicolor*

[image]
*O. sinensis*